# Create custom dialog box swiping on all 4 directions

Tags: flutter, dialog, modal-dialog

I'm new to Flutter and need to create a user comments dialog box. How can I implement that like the Facebook comments dialog box, which can be swiped away in all 4 directions? I tried `showGeneralDialog()` but that didn't do what I wanted.

Sample video here:

[image]